# Conflicts between jQuery and fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fancybox

My jQuery function gets info from a box and shows a external .html in a window fancybox. The html url is selected from the box value string. Here I have no problems with that.

I have a Legend shows the box value in categories. This legend I can show or hide it with on click (jQuery). This legend function works so good.

The problem is when I use my fancybox function then the legend function doesn´t work properly (I try to hide and it starts to hide and show in a cycle)

What can be the problem? Any idea?

Thank you.

The code:

```
$('#legend h3').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).hasClass("contracted")) {
        $(this).removeClass("contracted");
    }
    else {
        $(this).addClass("contracted");
    }
    $(this).parent().find('.content, .slider').slideToggle();
});


$(document).on("click", "#ctrl_info", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var unlo= $("#sidebar nav ul li.expanded .first_select option:selected").val().replace(/ /g, "_").toLowerCase() + ".html";
    var dolo= $("#sidebar nav ul li.expanded .second_select option:selected").val().replace(/ /g, "_").toLowerCase() + ".html";


    $.get("my_url/" + $("#sidebar nav ul li.expanded .first_select option:selected").val().toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, "_") + ".html", function (html) {
        $.fancybox(html);
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you post some code please

Comment: I will edit my above question ...